# Define Emacs org macro of html code

Tags: html, emacs, macros

I want to define a org mode macro of html code like below

`#+MACRO: img <div class="figure"><p><img src="dir/$1" alt="$1" width="$2"></p></div>`

Basically speaking, this macro intends to insert image $1 with width $2 into the org files. However, when I export it to html and open it, the macro is just replaced by the string "`<div class="figure"><p><img src="dir/$1" alt="$1" width="$2"></p></div>`".

Similarly, `#+MACRO: img #+attr_html: :width $2 \n [[file:dir/$1]]` doesn't work either.

Any ideas to solve this kind of issue? I tried to insert `#+BEGIN_HTML` and `#+END_HTML` into the macro, but still the macro is replaced by the string instead of html code....

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the first macro, I find it can be replaced by $#+MACRO: img @@html:<div class="figure"><p><img src="dir/$1" alt="$1" width="$2"></p></div>@@$, then the html code will not be parsed as just string. For the second macro, still no ideas...